# Index string to date time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

I am trying to convert my string index to DateTime and I used the following function:

```
df_wt_ist.index = pd.to_datetime(df_wt_ist.index)
```

Happens that it switches my months to my days, and it is wrong.
Does someone know another appropriate function?

Comment: What about `df_wt_ist.index = pd.to_datetime(df_wt_ist.index, dayfirst=True)`

Comment: Can you add some data sample? - 3-4 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible add parameter `dayfirst=True` to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df_wt_ist.index = pd.to_datetime(df_wt_ist.index, dayfirst=True)
```

For general solution use parameter format, e.g. for `DD-MM-YYYY`, for parameters check http://strftime.org/:

```
df_wt_ist.index = pd.to_datetime(df_wt_ist.index, format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: This works. otherwise, if not defined would switch my datetime (months per days)

Answer (score 2):

If your date is in the format dd-mm-yyyy, just add the parameter `dayfirst=True` to the `to_datetime` function:

```
df_wt_ist.index = pd.to_datetime(df_wt_ist.index, dayfirst=True)
```

if the format is yyyy-dd-mm also add `yearfirst=True`

```
df_wt_ist.index = pd.to_datetime(df_wt_ist.index, dayfirst=True, yearfirst=True)
```